# Interpreting DirectedInfinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am trying to calculate the right-handed limit of the following function using:

```
Q = Limit[Log[(H*(1 - c*g))/(1 + c - c*g)]/(g*(1 - c*g)),g -> 0, Direction -> -1,Assumptions -> {0 < c < 1, PositiveReals}];
```

Which gives:

```
DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]]
```

Can this be interpreted as infinity? I am very confused as to what DirectedInfinity means, even after reading previous posts on the matter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the complex plane, a ray can go off to infinity at any angle. `DirectedInfinity[z]` indicates something that approached infinity in the direction of the angle `Arg[z]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 So would it be incorrect to simply say that this function approaches infinity as $g\rightarrow0$?

Comment: It is wrong if `H = I` or `H < 1 + c`. Try the limit with `Assumptions -> {0 < c < 1, H > 1 + c}` instead. (Note: I don't think `PositiveReals` is a valid assumption. `PositiveReals` represents the set of positive real numbers. An assumption should be boolean.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I get it now; thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. Another way to discuss the limit: `DirectedInfinity` does mean the limit is infinite (though watch out for `H == 1 + c`). By "infinity," I assumed you meant positive infinity, which is what my US calc. students always mean. That's why I would say "it's infinite" instead of "it's infinity." And `Infinity` in Mathematica means positive infinity. But whether the limit it `Infinity` or `-Infinity` (or some complex infinity) depends on `H`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your comments would be worth memorializing in an answer, in my opinion. We have had a few questions on `DirectedInfinity` lately so it would be good to have a reference. I also like your last comment in particular.

Comment: ...and just to complete @Michael's notes, since we're already here: note that `Infinity` itself is internally represented as `DirectedInfinity[1]`, which does straightforwardly interpret as "infinity in the direction of the complex number $1$". We also have `ComplexInfinity` (internally, `DirectedInfinity[]`), where the direction is not determined at all.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. I added some gratuitous elaboration that I hope is helpful.  I'm pretty sure the `Log[0.]` thing came up before, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: `DirectedInfinity` is not a math notion, this is an invention of Mathematica developers only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*General discussion of `DirectedInfinity`*

In the complex plane, a ray can go off to infinity at any angle. `DirectedInfinity[z]` indicates quantity that approached a ray going off to infinity in the direction of the angle `Arg[z]`. To add J.M. further explanation, `Infinity` is short for `DirectedInfinity[1]`, infinity in direction of the complex number `1`. Likewise `-Infinity` is `DirectedInfinity[-1]` and `z * Infinity` is `DirectedInfinity[z]` (see also the second example below). Finally `ComplexInfinity` is `DirectedInfinity[]` with no direction specified; it usually indicates that the quantity is approaching infinity along different angles. For instance in `1/0`, the argument-angle of the denominator cannot be determined.

Another way to discuss the limit: `DirectedInfinity` does mean the limit is infinite (see the first example below for a pitfall). By "infinity," I assumed the OP meant positive infinity, which is what my US calc. students always mean. Also `Infinity` in Mathematica means positive infinity.  That's why I would say "it's infinite" instead of "it's infinity."  Whether the OP's limit is `Infinity` or `-Infinity` (or some complex infinity) depends on `H`.

*Examples with potentially unexpected outputs*

**1.** Like a lot of results in Mathematica, the OP's limit is only generically true. One needs to beware values of `H` or `c` for which `Log[H/(1 + c)]` becomes `0` and has an undefined argument-angle. `DirectedInfinity[0]` becomes `ComplexInfinity`, so you get an answer without an error message; but the answer is wrong:

```
DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]] /. H -> 1 + c
Limit[Log[(H*(1 - c*g))/(1 + c - c*g)]/(g*(1 - c*g)), g -> 0, 
 Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> {0 < c < 1, H == 1 + c}]
(*
ComplexInfinity
-((-1 + H)^2/H)
*)
```

**2.** When `z` is numeric, `z * Infinity` and `DirectedInfinity[z]` normalize `z` to `z/Abs[z]`.

[image]

**3.** I cannot explain $\log 0$ satisfactorily: When the argument is an exact `0`, the value is the limit at $0$. The approximate number `0.` represents a number in a neighborhood of $0$, a positive or negative real. When the argument is `0.`, then the limits from either side of `0.` are the same $-\infty$, unless you treat `Log[]` in the standard real-function way; however, the result of `Log[0.]` is `Indeterminate`, not `-Infinity`. Mathematica normally yields `Indeterminate` whenever there are multiple limits at point. So why `Indeterminate` if the limits are the same? Note that `Log[0. + 0. I]` is `Indeterminate`, too, so restricting `Log[0.]` to the standard real definition does not explain `0. + 0.I` case.

```
Log[0]
Log[0.]
(*
-∞
Indeterminate
*)
```

*Solving for infinity*

This is hard -- *update: harder*. It doesn't seem Mathematica has been programmed to do this.  For instance, suppose you wanted to deduce conditions on `H` or `c` for which OP's limit is `Infinity` (positive infinity).

Some first tries: `Solve` fails, `Reduce` gets it wrong.

```
Solve[DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]] == Infinity, H]
```

> Solve::infc: The system `DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1+c)]]==∞` contains an infinite object `DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1+c)]]`.

```
Reduce[DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]] == Infinity, {H, c}]
(*  False  *)
```

You have to map `DirectedInfinity` to `Arg` and (*update:* exclude `Arg[0]`).  I'm throwing the assumptions back in, but they don't help the above cases:

```
Reduce[
 DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]] == Infinity &&
   0 < c < 1 && H ∈ Reals /.
    DirectedInfinity[z_] :> ConditionalExpression[Arg[z], z != 0],
 {H, c}]
(*  (1 < H < 2 && 0 < c < -1 + H) || (H >= 2 && 0 < c < 1)  *)
```

This is cool, it works:

```
Limit[
 Log[(H*(1 - c*g))/(1 + c - c*g)]/(g*(1 - c*g)),
 g -> 0, Direction -> -1,
 Assumptions -> Reduce[
   DirectedInfinity[Log[H/(1 + c)]] == Infinity &&
     0 < c < 1 && H ∈ Reals /. 
    DirectedInfinity[z_] :> ConditionalExpression[Arg[z], z != 0],
   {H, c}]
 ]

(*  ∞  *)
```

(Note: The option `GenerateConditions -> True` for `Limit` does not generate conditions in this case.)

Comment: In "the argument of `Log[z]`", does one mean `z` or `Arg[Log[z]]`? I hope I've kept the distinction clear. I used "argument-angle" at times to hopefully make clear I meant the complex-number argument. (Who invented this name, anyway?)

Comment: thank you for putting this together. (+1)

Comment: The terminological confusion is why some authors prefer to use "phase" (and thus $\operatorname{ph}(z)$) instead of "argument" (and thus $\arg(z)$), but alas, we are stuck with `Arg[]`. ;) Additionally: "normalize `z` to `z/Abs[z]`" is basically what `Sign[z]` does for complex `z`. ;) (In polar coordinate terms, `Arg[z]` is $\theta$, and `Sign[z]` is (effectively, excluding $0$) $\exp(i\theta)$.) (cc. @Marco)

Comment: "By "infinity," I assumed the OP meant positive infinity, which is what my US calc. students always mean" it is not that simple, as any normal textbook says: if you have limit at finite point then sure, left and right limits should be the same: 1/x in 0 does not exist, Mathematica knows that since 12.0. Or x^x, limit in 0 does exist. But when we talk about +Infinity limit, we are allowed to have an oscilation that goes to plus and minus infinity both, that means the limit is infinite without a sign. Or function can oscilate without infinity between 1 and 0, then limit does not exist.

Comment: As an example n Sin[n] behaves like this, though mathematica says limit does not exist.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников "when we talk about +Infinity limit, we are allowed to have an oscilation that goes to plus and minus infinity both" -- that is not how infinite limits are defined in most US calc. courses. There are historical and regional differences throughout the world, I believe, but I am not familiar with all of them. Here is a typical explanation, in which the $+$ is omitted from $+\infty$ as usual (in the US): https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/infinitelimits.aspx -- Some courses will substitute appropriate inequalities for "arbitrarily large" etc.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I would say the limit of $n \sin n$ does not exist, too. What definition do you use to conclude it exists? -- If this is to be a long discussion, it is maybe better in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica

Comment: The limit does exist if we consider infinity without a sign and because right and left limits are impossible for limit at +Infinity...

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I don't think your definitions are the same as mine. You need to state your definitions for me to follow what you're saying. There is no difference for me between infinity without a sign and +infinity. (By the limit "at" +Infinity, do you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x)$? Or are we still talking about $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=+\infty$?)

Comment: I meant the first one. This function is unbounded at infinity, so you can say the limit is from -Infinity to +Infinity or just Infinity if we consider like on a Riemann sphere only one Infinity. I read it in some book :)

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников (1) I think to discuss `DirectedInfinity`, it's best to stick to Mathematica's definitions. (2) I don't think it is correct to say "the limit is from $a$ to $b$" if $a$ and $b$ are distinct. I understand what it means that the limit is infinite (that is, approaching the north pole on the Riemann sphere); however $n \sin n$ does not approach the north pole on the Riemann sphere, not as $n\rightarrow+\infty$, nor $n\rightarrow-\infty$, nor $|n|\rightarrow\infty$. It goes back and forth around the Riemann sphere infinitely often, always passing through the south pole ($z=0$).